# Firebase NSNull Exception while taking Snapshot of Data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i was making a Firebase practice app and i encountered this problem. Where i got NSNull exception while capturing a value from Firebase database. Here is the code

```
user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    let userid = user.uid
    if userid != nil
    {
        print("User Nid \(userid)")
        ref.child("users").child(userid).observe(.value, with: {
            (snapshot) in
            if(snapshot.exists()){
                var user_details = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "\(userid)")
                var user_det = user_details.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
                print("User Name \(user_det["name"])")
            }
            else{
                print("Does not exist")
            }
        })

    }
```

and here is the database.

> - uid
>
>   - user-details
>
>     - name: "Salman"
>     - propic: "picurl"

Comment: which line you got the `NSNull exception`

Comment: var user_details = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "\(userid)")

Comment: This line @NazmulHasan

Comment: check my updated answer and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try with this way

```
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  // Get user value
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    if  let userDetail= value?["user-details"] as? [String:Any] {
         // let username = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let username = userDetail["name"] as? String ?? ""
    }

  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```